# How to show history of different branch in EGit for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I want to cherry pick some commits of a specific git branch into my currently checked out branch.

To do that I would like to filter the history view EGit offers to see only that one branch.

I know that there's a toggle button that allows me to switch between the display of the commits of the current branch and all branches ([image: Toggle button for all branches]). This allows me to see the commits done in the other branch. Though with all the commits of the other branches shown, this gets confusing quickly.

Similarily, there is a button allowing me to select the input, for which the commits are shown ([image: Button to switch the input, for which to show commits for]). Though that button only allow to filter the commits by workspace resources of the currently checked out branch.

There is also a button to pin the current history view ([image: Button to pin current history view]), but it doesn't seem to work when I switch between the two branches, the view still gets refreshed.

So, Is there an option, that allows me to restrict the display of commits to a specific branch? Or is there an option to pin the view, so I can keep seeing the commits of the one branch when I check out the other branch?

Comment: You can used the gitbash

Comment: Of course, it is possible by using the command line. Though I would really prefer a way integrated into Eclipse.

Comment: You like see the full hisory

Comment: This worked for me: go to `Git repositories view -> your repository -> branchA -> Show in (R click) -> History -> (pint this view)`, Do the same with other branch, a **New** view should be opened.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz When I gave my answer, I overlooked that you already answered the question by your comment. I have deleted my answer and I hope that you will give the answer.

Comment: Very kind of you @howlger :-) .

Answer (score 2):

This worked for Eclipse Oxygen:

- Go to: ***Git Repositories*** view -> your repository -> branchA -> right-click and choose ***Show in > History*** -> (pin this view)
- Do the same with other branch, a new view should be opened

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't do the trick for me. It only selects the chosen branch's last commit in the history view and requires the button "Show All Branches and Tags" to be enabled. That means it requires to display all branches instead of filtering the commits related to the selected branch.

Answer (score 1):

Because I couldn't find an option how to restrict the shown commits to a specific branch, I [filed a bug in Eclipse's bug tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536275).

The answer there was that the code for the input only distinguishes between repositories and files and it currently disregards branches. So it looks like it is not possible to restrict the display of the commits to a specified branch at the moment.